# Class "Container" bootstrap not working with direction

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a class bootstrap "Container" in my div. inner div with class "row pricing",
When I added dir="ltr" to the main div it's not responsive. The question is why? because in class "table" bootstrap it is working...
Anybody has an answer?

Comment: you should have to post your code so we need to edit that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WHY?**

I guess there are a lot of declaretions of bootstrap in css that override the `dir` for example `float` and ect...

**To resolve this issue:**

You have to download `rtl` version of bootstrap

[See here doc for bootstrap 4](http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/)

[See here doc for bootstrap 3](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-rtl)

For example bootstrap-4 **rtl**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-P4uhUIGk/q1gaD/NdgkBIl3a6QywJjlsFJFk7SPRdruoGddvRVSwv5qFnvZ73cpz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-54+cucJ4QbVb99v8dcttx/0JRx4FHMmhOWi4W+xrXpKcsKQodCBwAvu3xxkZAwsH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button class="btn btn-danger">rtl</button>
```

Comment: happy to help :) בהצלחה